# Apple push APNS connection

Tags: java, ios, ssl

I am trying to connect to Apple's push notification server to send down notifications but I am having some issues connecting. After I attempt the handshake, it shows that says that I am not connected. I am not getting any exceptions? It isn't a issue with my certificate because I tried using 3rd party libraries with the certificate and I was able to push with no problem.

```
int port = 2195;
String hostname = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com";
char[] passwKey = "password".toCharArray();

KeyStore ts = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ts.load(new FileInputStream("/path/to/file/Cert.p12"), passwKey);
KeyManagerFactory tmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
tmf.init(ts, passwKey);

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(tmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
SSLSocketFactory factory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(hostname,port); 
String[] suites = socket.getSupportedCipherSuites();
socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(suites);
//start handshake
socket.startHandshake();

//THIS ALWAYS RETURNS FALSE
boolean connected = socket.isConnected();
```

Comment: Why are you screaming in your headline? This isn't polite.

Comment: Are you connecting directly from your app? I'm pretty sure you need to have a man-in-the-middle server between your app and Apple.

Comment: This is the server connecting to apple, a payload would be sent to apple which would push the notification to the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This always returns false, but I was able to communicate with no problems. 
boolean connected = socket.isConnected();